# Flask: url_for working in one instance but not in another

Tags: flask

For some reason, the url_for command is working fine in the 'about' route but not for the 'home'.

Please see the code snippet below:
**File: templates/layout.html (this is the main template site)**

```
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <!--<a class="nav-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/about">About</a>-->
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('about')}}">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Help</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This works fine and I can toggle between About and Home.

However, when I change the 'home' link to use url_for, it just doesn't work.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('home')}}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

Giving this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'string'
```

and this:

```
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject\templates\layout.html", line 26, in template
<a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('home')">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'string'
```

I added the extra curly braces, but still get an error:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('home')}}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

**Errors:**

```
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 2179, in build
raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'home'. Did you mean 'hello_world' instead?
```

**Another error:**

```
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject\templates\layout.html", line 26, in top-level template code
<a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('home')}}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

I cannot make sense of either error in order to fix the code.

Finally, with this code, I cannot even open the localhost/about route, as it gives **this error:**

**templates/layout.html (this is the main template site)**

```
 <title>Laptop review site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><b><font color="#ffc60a">LR</font></b></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">


        <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('home')}}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <!--<a class="nav-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/about">About</a>-->
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('about')}}">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Help</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>




werkzeug.routing.BuildError
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'home'. Did you mean 'hello_world' instead?
```

I wonder if this has something to do with it. This is where the route is defined and called:

**laptopreview.py**

```
@app.route('/') #this is what we type into our browser to go to pages. we create these using routes
@app.route('/home')
def hello_world():
    #we will now have access to this reviwes data in our template
    return render_template('home.html',reviews=reviews)
```

Finally, if it is useful, here is the whole error log, on going to the url: **http://127.0.0.1:5000/home**

**Entire Error Log**

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'home'. Did you mean 'hello_world' instead?

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject\laptopreview.py", line 32, in hello_world
return render_template('home.html',reviews=reviews)
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 137, in render_template
return _render(
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 120, in _render
rv = template.render(context)
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1090, in render
self.environment.handle_exception()
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject\templates\home.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends "layout.html" %}
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject\templates\layout.html", line 26, in top-level template code
<a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('home')}}">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 370, in url_for
return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2216, in handle_url_build_error
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 357, in url_for
rv = url_adapter.build(
File "E:\Python installation\myproject\env\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 2179, in build
raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'home'. Did you mean 'hello_world' instead?
```

Answer (score 0):

The error had to do with the fact that in this case we are using url_for and then the **FUNCTION** name not the **html page name**. I just verified this. As a Flask newbie, it wasn't obvious to me that we were using method names (contained in the main .py file) rather than the html page names themselves. Of course, this makes sense now.

I simply changed the method (listed in the laptopreview.py file) to home (from hello_world) and it worked!